# How can I write this JS code more simple, smarter?

Tags: javascript

I need shorter, smarter code becuase there is a lot of these shapes with different IDs.

```
const shape1 = document.getElementById('shape1');
const shape2 = document.getElementById('shape2');
const shape3 = document.getElementById('shape3');
const shape4 = document.getElementById('shape4');
const shape5 = document.getElementById('shape5');

shape1.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
    shape1.style.color = color
});
shape2.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
    shape2.style.color = color
});
shape3.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
    shape3.style.color = color
});
shape4.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
    shape4.style.color = color
});
shape5.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
    shape5.style.color = color
});
```

Comment: Do you want this five element has the same color?

Comment: Use a `class` instead of an `ID` and just iterate over the results.

Comment: Yes, I want them to have the same color. Can't use classes because I need to target each shapes with IDs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get all elements and then loop for them

like this:

```
// get elements by ID that STARTS WITH shape
const shapes  = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="shape"]`);

shapes.forEach(shape=> {
  shape.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shape.style.color = color;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one function with `data-attribute` like:

```js
const shapes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-shape]');

shapes.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.style.color = e.target.dataset.shape;
  });
});
```

```html
<div data-shape='red'>click me</div>
<div data-shape='blue'>click me</div>
<div data-shape='green'>click me</div>
```

Reference:

- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)